# Golang object scoping with loops and threads

Tags: go

It's clear I don't understand something about scoping. I've distilled the problem down to the following ([run it at The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d4WMf5sIxe1)):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type mystruct struct {
    mybool bool
}

func new() mystruct {
    var ms mystruct
    go func() {
            for {
                    time.Sleep(time.Second/2)
                    log.Println("loop says:",ms.mybool)
            }
    }()
    return ms
}

func (m *mystruct) switchIt() {
    if m.mybool {
            m.mybool = false
    } else {
            m.mybool = true
    }
}

func main() {
    thing := new()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    thing.switchIt()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    thing.switchIt()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    thing.switchIt()
}
```

As it is now, the boolean is always `false` from the perspective of the endless loop in `new()`'s anonymous function. I'm trying to change that value with `switchIt()` while the loop runs.

Moving the boolean to a global variable gives the behavior I want (value changed from the loop's perspective), but I need the boolean to be part of the object because there will be several instantiations of the object.

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code a bit, and now it works as your expectation.

---

### Code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "time"
)

type mystruct struct {
    mybool bool
}

func newThing() *mystruct {
    var ms mystruct
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second / 2)
            log.Println("loop says:", ms.mybool)
        }
    }()
    return &ms
}

func (m *mystruct) switchIt() {
    if m.mybool {
        m.mybool = false
    } else {
        m.mybool = true
    }
}

func main() {
    thing := newThing()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    thing.switchIt()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    thing.switchIt()

    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    thing.switchIt()
}
```

---

### Tips

**Issues of your code:**

- I changed your `new()` to `newThing()`, because it's confusing with the built-in `new()` function.
  Even though you can write it that way, but it's error-prone.
- Your original `new()` returns a copy of the struct, thus after calling `new()`, there are 2 copies of the struct, that's why you can never change it.
  In this case it's better to return a pointer instead.

**Tips on `go`:**

- For `struct`, when assign / pass as param / return from function, it always makes a copy.
  You have 2 options to conquer this:

  - Use a pointer instead.
    In that case there is only one copy of the struct.
  - Let fields in the struct be pointers or similar reference types *(e.g slice or map)*.
    In that case, there are 2 copies of the struct, but those fields refer to the same underling data structure.
    But in you code, `bool` is not a reference type, so can't use this.
- Similar to `struct`, `array` behavior similarly.
  Though most of the time, you will only use `slice` instead.
- On the other, `slice` / `map` contain reference to underling data structure that hold the actual data.
  So, if you assign a slice to another slice variable, or return it from a function, there will be 2 `slice`, but they still refer to the same underling data structure *(an `array`)*.
  Thus, changes made to one slice would be visible to the other.

BTW, [Effective go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) is a good place to pick up these tricky details about go :)

Comment: Thank you! I get it. Fantastic explanation.